# Showing the set of $2\times 2$ matrices of a certain form over $\mathbb Z$ is a ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory

[Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jjl9j.png)
[image]

Could anyone help me, please?

Comment: It looks like a pretty clear, straightforward question. What did you try and what are you having problems with? For (a) you need to check the ring axioms are fulfilled, which seems pretty easy to achieve though, perhaps, a little lengthy and boring thing to do. Part (b) is even easier, and you need to calculate only 2-3 powers in order to get a feeling and then directly with induction

Comment: You need to show this is closed under addition, subtraction, and multiplication. The first two are trivial. Now multiply: $$ \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & c \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} d & e \\ 0 & f \end{bmatrix} = \cdots $$ See if you get a matrix of the required form, i.e. a $0$ in the $(2,1)$ position. $\qquad$

Comment: @DonAntonio Pues probar que (S, +) es un grupo abeliano es claro ya que la suma de matrices es asociativa, conmutativa, tiene como elemento neutro a la matriz nula 2x2 y cada elemento tiene inverso aditivo. Además tenemos que la multiplicación de matrices es asociativa con lo cual se muestra que S es un anillo.

Comment: @DonAntonio La parte (b) necesariamente tiene que ser por inducción? No podría hacerse simplemente \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ 0 &c\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & c \end{bmatrix} = todo esto k veces?

Comment: @Nash ¿Cuánto es "k veces"? ¿Mil veces, cien mil veces...? No veo otra manera de hacerlo **formalmente** que haciendo inducción...la cual, en este caso, es muy sencilla. Ahora, si necesitas algo no muy formal entonces sí te puedes saltar la inducción...pero te muestro ahora, en las respuestas abajo, cómo hacerlo fácilmente.

Comment: @DonAntonio Ok, sí es mejor por inducción para hacerlo bien formal, muchas gracias. Usted podría ayudarme con más problemas de álgebra?

Comment: @Nash Colócalas en este sitio. Trataré de ayudar cuando pueda, pero recuerda: aquí es importante también el escribir, junto a la pregunta, lo que has logrado, qué tanto has avanzado, en dónde te atoraste, etc. Una pregunta como la que hiciste en este caso, como podrás ver, puede ser cerrada por no mostrar que ya hiciste un verdadero esfuerzo por resolverla.

Comment: @DonAntonio Comprendo eso perfectamente, no copio mucho porque mi inglés es muy malo pero sí le intento demasiado a cada cuestión y la pienso mucho antes de publicarla....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Induction on $\;k\;$ for (b):

$$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&c\end{pmatrix}^k=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&c\end{pmatrix}^{k-1}\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&c\end{pmatrix}\stackrel{\text{Ind. Hyp.}}=\begin{pmatrix}a^{k-1}&n\\0&c^{k-1}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&c\end{pmatrix}\;,\;\;n\in\Bbb Z=$$

$$=\begin{pmatrix}a^k&a^{k-1}b+nc\\0&c^k\end{pmatrix}\;,\;\;\text{and also}\;\;a^{k-1}b+nc\in\Bbb Z\;\text{ since }\;a,b,c,n\in\Bbb Z$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

For idempotent elements 
$$
\pmatrix{a& b\\0 & c}^2=\pmatrix{a^2 & ab+bc\\0 & c^2}=\pmatrix{a &b\\0 & c}
$$
So $a=0, 1\: c=0,1$, and either $b=0$ or $a+c=1$.

For nilpotent elements
$$
\pmatrix{a& b\\0 & c}^k=\pmatrix{a^k & *\\0 & c^k}=0
$$
So $a=c=0$. Clearly
$$
\pmatrix{0& b\\0 & 0}^2=0
$$